# I can't select HTML5 when presented with Facebook page timeline plugin code

Tags: facebook, html

I'm creating a Facebook page plugin using the tool [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin), and I was [lead to believe](http://www.survivalguide4idiots.com/facebook-plugins-available-in-html5-update.html) I would have the option of selecting HTML5 from a drop down box.

However, there are no options to select from.

I only see:

> 1. Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening `<body>` tag.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=171705736232531";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

> 2. Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.

```
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/example.com" data-tabs="timeline" data-small-header="false" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true"><div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore"><blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/example.com"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/example.com">Example</a></blockquote></div></div>
```

Is this code HTML5 by default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this code HTML5 by default?

Yes, HTML5 would seem to be the default (and only) option these days.

Previously, there were additional options for "XFBML", "IFRAME" and "URL". But these would have resulted in very different plugin code to copy 'n' paste.